# using preSend() and getSentMIMEMessage() instead of send() in PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

i'm trying to make an adjustment in the absence of my developer who has upped and left. I am trying to overcome a much-discussed issue re GoDaddy's SMTP restrictions. Synchro has already kindly supplied an answer, but i'm afraid i need to be walked hand-in-hand to make the adjustment.

```js
function sendMail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
 // Load up the site settings
 global $settings;

 // If the SMTP emails option is enabled in the Admin Panel
 if($settings['smtp_email']) {
  require_once(__DIR__ .'/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

  //Create a new PHPMailer instance
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
  $mail->isSMTP();
  //Enable SMTP debugging
  // 0 = off (for production use)
  // 1 = client messages
  // 2 = client and server messages
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
  //Set the CharSet encoding
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
  $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
  //Set the hostname of the mail server
  $mail->Host = $settings['smtp_host'];
  //Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
  $mail->Port = $settings['smtp_port'];
  //Whether to use SMTP authentication
  $mail->SMTPAuth = $settings['smtp_auth'] ? true : false;
  //Username to use for SMTP authentication
  $mail->Username = $settings['smtp_username'];
  //Password to use for SMTP authentication
  $mail->Password = $settings['smtp_password'];
  //Set who the message is to be sent from
  $mail->setFrom($from, $settings['title']);
  //Set an alternative reply-to address
  $mail->addReplyTo($from, $settings['title']);
  //Set who the message is to be sent to
  if(is_array($to)) {
   foreach($to as $address) {
    $mail->addAddress($address);
   }
  } else {
   $mail->addAddress($to);
  }
  //Set the subject line
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
  //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
  $mail->msgHTML($message);

  //send the message, check for errors
  if(!$mail->send()) {
   // Return the error in the Browser's console
   //echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }
 } else {
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'From: '.$from.'' . "\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: '.$from . "\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  if(is_array($to)) {
   foreach($to as $address) {
    @mail($address, $subject, $message, $headers);
   }
  } else {
   @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
 }
}
```

QUESTION: - how does one substitute the send() with preSend() and getSentMIMEMessage()?

Thanks in advance for assisting this major-newbie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    // Return the error in the Browser's console
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Do this:

```
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->preSend()) {
    // Return the error in the Browser's console
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    $message = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
}
```

`preSend()` still does most of the checking of the structure of the message and validity of addresses etc, but doesn't actually send it. `getSentMIMEMessage()` fetches a complete RFC822 message that you can send some other way - e.g. by posting to an HTTP-based email service's API, or using PHP's `mail()` function directly.

Comment: Thanks Synchro - much appreciated!!

Comment: Just to check - this substitution is all that is required, or- as you have indicated (?) at the end of your response i will require further building to incorporate use with, say Mailgun's service and their HTTP-based API?

(hopefully getting another coder on board soon ...)

Thanks again

Comment: Yes, the complete message will be in `$message` ready for you to pass into whatever sending mechanism you like, but you will need additional code to implement that. Mailgun and others may control some sending functions via custom headers in the message, which you can add with `addCustomHeader()`.

Comment: the light was misleading - don't seem to be to able achieve the desired result. By way of a workaround - as already described, i currently have mydomain.xyz hosted by Godaddy where i am met with the SMTP restrictions for any email address associated with it. i also own mydomain.com on eNOM where i can manage the relevant DNS credentials and create email aliases which i am using with MailGun. At the risk of sounding dumb - would it be viable to use these domain.com credentials instead? I suspect i already know the answer....

Comment: It's not the credentials that are stopping you sending, so that won't help, but it shouldn't stop you using mailgun.

Comment: Understood. The only solution that has worked so far has been with GoDaddy SMTP credentials BUT only using their non-secure port 80. Using the debug, and when i change to secure port 465 i get a SMTP error  failed to connect - which doesn't make sense? 

I can post both debug scripts for success and failed messages, if it would help, but i don't see why the script /phpMailer is working only for the unsecured port80 and not the secure one 465. It doesn't help if i'm sending out non-secure messages which are immediately flagged by recipients

Comment: Here's an idea - could i incorporate another step in the mailing process:

1) phpMailer script on my site sends registration confirmation (from mail@godaddyhostedsite.com) not directly to the subscriber but...
2) to another fixed address (eg mail@gmail.cpm) which then forwards it to
3) intended user? (It will be donotreply address so am not bothered about replies to registration/welcome emails)


Thinking out aloud, i'm already suspecting this to be more difficult than i am making it out to be...